# If $\Gamma \subset \Delta$, then $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ implies $\Delta \vdash \phi$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have just started learning propositonal logic and I would like to prove that for two sets of formulas $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$, if $\Gamma \subset \Delta$, then $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ implies $\Delta \vdash \phi$. This should be easy, but I got stuck.
So, if $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, we have three cases:
$\bullet$ $\phi$ is an axiom and then we have nothing to prove.
$\bullet$ $\phi \in \Gamma$ and then we have that $\phi \in \Delta$ and we are done again.
$\bullet$ there is some $\psi$ such that $\Gamma \vdash \psi$ and $\Gamma \vdash \psi \rightarrow \phi$. This is where I got stuck and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @EricWofsey sorry if this is really trivial, but could you give me some further details please? I feel really lost, even though I have been trying to understand these notions...

Comment: Have you seen any other proofs by induction on derivation structure? The fine details depend on the details of how your derivations are laid out, but the idea is that since the derivations witnessing $\Gamma\vdash \psi$ and $\Gamma\vdash \psi\to \phi$ are subproofs of the derivation of $\Gamma\vdash\phi,$ you can assume an induction hypothesis that the theorem holds for them, so then $\Delta\vdash\psi$ and $\Delta\vdash\psi\to\phi,$ and you have $\Delta\vdash\phi.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thank you, now I get it!